# The resource cannot be found on web form when using crystal reports and after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, crystal-reports, web-deployment

every other form is working fine but one which has crystal report First asking for server's username and password when i provide username password then it show this error 
Server Error in '/Reports' Application.
The resource cannot be found.

my application root folder has full rights for users 'everyone' ,iuser,iusers_iis....
admin ,and the account which i am using .

i checked, the resource exists ,I browsed the .aspx file from iis then hit browse it should be opened in browser even then it shows resource cannot be found.

i have used asp.net website as project
but if i run my website from visual studio it works fine and no prompting for username and password of my server.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: And the DLL:s related to CR is in the /bin folder?

Comment: i saw in visulal studio all the dll it refrecned to gac for Cr related dlls

then i just installed redist_64 bit installer at server as server is 64 bit